# Mpeg TS player on android using GStreamer

Tags: android, ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpeg2-ts

I am supposed to design a MPEG-TS demux and player in android on my win 7 platform using the libraries of GStreamer as well as ffmpeg. I am using eclipse juno version in my win 7 system. Now, I was successfully able to configure ffmpeg in eclipse. I downloaded GStreamer sdk from docs.gstreamer.com and successfully configured gstreamer in eclipse. As it turns out, the 5th tutorial of GStreamer is a media player app only. But when I execute that project, I am not able to see the video. Only audio sound is heard. So, my next step should be configuring gst-ffmpeg plug-in in my eclipse and code a media player accepting transport stream (.ts) files. But after surfing a lot on internet, I am not able to get a single solution of moving further. I am using windows platform so the problem increases a bit. I am aware that there is Vplayer that accepts files of .ts format. But I am not able to reach to the source code of Vplayer. Can anyone please please guide me further? Help needed.

Comment: I suggest to try using linux for that. Is Windows needed? gst-launch is great tool and most about gstreamer is unix based. Unless you have working gst-inspect and such tools, I suggest you try to install at least virtual machine with linux and gstreamer libraries. And study a lot, it is not so simple.

Comment: Yes, due to windows platform, I am not able to know which plug-ins are missing, as gst-inspect is not working properly. So. can I install gst-launch as well as virtual machine first? Also, do you have any useful links or references to materials related to this topic?

Comment: @Ruchi Hi even I am using Win 7 and Juno...I sucessfully played a hls m3u8 in jellybean using Gstreamer.But currently I am stuck in Gingerbread and ics..Can u please guide me in this issue..I have used the following plugin in Android.mk mpeg2dec mpegdemux2 mpegtsdemux mpegtsmux ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646907/gstreamer-issue-in-ics-and-gingerbread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying Android.mk in jni folder to include the following plugins in GSTREAMER_PLUGINS:

```
mpeg2dec mpegdemux2 mpegtsdemux mpegtsmux
```

Then re-build. TS files (found on your SD card) should now play.

If you need other plugins, check plugins.mk in GStreamerSDK/share/gst-android/ndk-build/

Comment: Hey it worked. But some ts files are not getting played. The emulator is showing the message **internal data stream error** What could be the reason?

Comment: I have not used the emulator with GStreamer - it has limitations with video stuff - but not sure. Best to use a real device for testing...

Comment: Do you have any idea how to receive the mpeg ts stream in my gstreamer application over udp? I have been trying to receive the stream by giving the uri **udp://10.61.124.141:1234** and sending the data from vlc. But it is not working.

Comment: I would've thought that'll work. Try playing first in MX player to make sure the stream is OK. Otherwise try http instead - that is what I use because I want reliable communication with no packet drop.

Comment: Actually, I am supposed to use udp only in my project. I made sure that the stream is a transport stream. But still no luck. Is there any other mechanism of receiving packets over udp in android? Or is it because I am testing it on emulator?

Comment: @barkside Hii...These plugins worked for me.But I am having issues in ics and gingerbread... Can you please guide on this....I am having a m3u8 file on the server and streaming it using Gstreamer...Please help...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646907/gstreamer-issue-in-ics-and-gingerbread